# Controlling vote

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Setting**
Suppose $n$ students plan to go $m$ tourist spots $s_1, \cdots, s_m$ together. But it turns out that the schedule is tight. So they decide to go $(m - 1)$ tourist spots instead. To determine which spot to be removed, they plan vote: each student has $m$ points to vote and the spot which gets the  lowest points will be removed.

**Question**
Is it possible to go the spot $s_1$ if one student votes properly? More formally, if we write $p(s_i, v)$ for points that a spot $s_i$ gets in a vote $v$, 
$$ p_{n, m} := \max_v \min_{1 \leq i \leq m} p(s_i, v) < m $$
holds? If so (or if not), what is the value of $p_{n, m}$?

Without proper assumption, it does not likely to hold. In case $n = 3$ and $m = 2$, if other two students vote for $2$ points to the spot $s_2$ then spot $s_1$ will be removed. So I feel $n < m$ is needed. Anyway, I don't come up with a solution. (How to handle this question mathematically?) Would you help me? Just a suggestion for a specific case is also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other $n-1$ students have $(n-1)m$ votes in total. There are $m-1$ spots other than $s_1$, so they can boost all of them up to at least $\lfloor(n-1)m/(m-1)\rfloor$. Thus, roughly speaking they can prevent $s_1$ if $n\gt m$, but to get the exact bound the $-1$ terms have to be taken into account, and you'd need to specify what happens in case of a tie.

A more usual procedure would be for $m-1$ to be chosen by each person casting $m-1$ votes. That would simpify the problem, since in this case the other $n-1$ students could boost the other spots up to $n-1$.

Comment: As you said, I should add some assumptions or rules to avoid a tie... Does anyone come up with appropriate ones?

A simple procedure that you suggested seems to me too simple; it is easy to solve, but it's not practical procedure for students to determine which *one* to remove. Or simply it's not fun to think about.

Comment: @Taro: I don't see why it's not a practical procedure. It's standard procedure in the German Green party, and I believe also in other parties, to elect $k$ people by each voter casting up to $k$ votes and the $k$ people with the most votes being elected. The analogue here would be for everyone to cast $m-1$ votes to select $m-1$ spots to go to.

Comment: I understand it's quite natural procedure. Somehow, I tried to rank spots in order and I introduce the vote above so that if one can vote evenly in case he has no preference. Do you have some idea in case $n < m$?

Comment: @Taro: Some idea for what?

Comment: For evaluating $p_{n, m}$ (from above).

Comment: @Taro: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Why isn't $p_{m,n}$ just $n$? The highest minimum is attained when the votes are distributed uniformly, and then each spot gets a vote from each student, for a total of $n$, no?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I didn't understood what I asked. Thank you.